# Need to find mouse press count for my qwidget qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating a simple music player in qt.
I have created a QWidget called "nextButton" and I want to know how many times I have clicked that. Based on that number I can change the songs as specified by the user. How do I do that?

Comment: Start with an `on_nextButton_clicked()` slot in your `QWidget` that will be triggered every time the button is pressed. In that slot increment a counter you have in your widget.

Comment: You should study about signals and slots. This is the very core feature of Qt. Counting number of clicks on a button is the most trivial use case.

Comment: @Anonyman did you mean getting clicking counts in some time period?

Comment: What is your problem with just counting the clicks? Or just calling "next song" method every time the button is clicked, and the the "next song" method takes care of going forward one more, even if previous "next song" has not yet started playing?

Answer (score 1):

In your class constructor, declare a connection between your button and a custom slot :

```
connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(pressedNext()));
```

Then implement the corresponding slot :

```
void myclass::pressedNext()
{
   myCounter++;
}
```

But to fully answer, you may want to consider adding a kind of timer to wait a small moment before actually changing the song. Like "oh, you just pushed the button, so I'll skip ONE song in one second. If during this second you push again the button, I'll skip more !"

Hope that helps.